# Ocultar campos con un select en react

Tags: reactjs

Buen día, quiero hacer un formulario que aparezca dinámico de acuerdo con el valor que se trae en un select.

por ahora tengo el siguiente codigo del select

```
<div className='card'>
                <div className='card-content'>
                    <form>
                    <label htmlFor='profile'>Perfil</label>
                    <div className='input-field col s12 m12 l12'>                         
                        <i className='material-icons prefix'>contacts</i>
                                    <select >
                                        {
                                            this.state.getProfile.map((profile)=>
                                                <option key={profile.value} value={profile.value}>{profile.text}</option>
                                            )
                                        }
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div className='row'>
                        <div className='col s12 m10 l10'>
                            <button type='button' className="btn-floating btn waves-effect waves-light" data-position="bottom" onClick={this.state.getChange}><i className="material-icons right">check</i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Lo que quiero es que cuando seleccione una de las 3 opciones que hay dentro del select me muestre diferentes campos de un formulario que por lo pronto esta de la siguiente manera ya que no se como puedo hacerlo

```
<div className='card-panel'>
                                <div ref={ref => this.profile = ref} className='col s12 m12 l12'>
                                <div className= 'row'>
                                <div className='input-field col s12 m3 l3'>
                                    <i className="material-icons prefix">business</i>
                                    <input ref={ref => this.refInputBussinesname = ref} type="text" />
                                    <label htmlFor="bussines" className='validate'>Bussines Name</label>
                                </div>
                            <div className='input-field col s12 m4 l4'>
                                <i className="material-icons prefix">email</i>
                                    <input ref={ref => this.refInputEmail = ref} type="email" />
                                    <label htmlFor="email" className='validate'>E-mail</label>
                            </div>
                            <div className='input-field col s12 m4 l4'>
                                <i className="material-icons prefix">web</i>
                                <input ref={ref => this.refInputWebSite = ref} type="url" />
                                <label htmlFor="WebSite" className='validate'>WebSite</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='row'>
                        <div className='col s12 m10 l10'>
                            <button type='button' className="btn waves-effect waves-light" data-position="bottom" onClick={this.value}><i className="material-icons right">search</i>SEARCH CLIENT</button>
                        </div>
```

Espero haberme explicado bien y espero me puedan ayudar... quedare pendiente de sus posibles respuestas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Tienes que guardar el valor del campo seleccionado en el select (puede ser en el state del componente).
2. Basado en el valor almacenado en el punto anterior, condicionas la parte del formulario que deseas mostrar, por ejemplo:

   ```
                            { this.state.profiledSelected === 1 &&
                             <div className='input-field col s12 m3 l3'>
                               <i className="material-icons 
                                prefix">business</i>
                               <input ref={ref => 
                              this.refInputBussinesname = 
                                ref} type="text" />
                               <label htmlFor="bussines" 
                               className='validate'>Bussines Name</label>
                           </div>
                           } 
                           { this.state.profiledSelected === 2 &&
                             <div className='input-field col s12 m3 l3'>
                               <i className="material-icons 
                                prefix">business</i>
                               <input ref={ref => 
                              this.refInputBussinesname = 
                                ref} type="text" />
                               <label htmlFor="bussines" 
                               className='validate'>E-mail</label>
                           </div>
                           }
   ```